# jquery selector of the form $('xxxx', domnode); is it documented?

Tags: jquery

An example from dataTable shows:

```
 var cell = $('td:eq(2)', nRow);
```

`nRow` is a DOM node passed in by dataTable. Sure enough, this grabs the second td in nRow. The question is, why? Where is this syntax documented?

Comment: It is documented as the answers show, but it is just getting flipped around to `$(nRow).find('td:eq(2)');` by jQuery, so it's a little quicker to just use `.find()` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's documented.

Here: [jQuery( selector, [context] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1)

The second parameter is the context where the selector is applied. It can be a DOM element, the `document` object, or a jQuery object.

Answer (score 4):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

`$('selector', domnode)` is equivalent to `$(domnode).find('selector')`.

Answer (score 2):

This is proper behavior. The second parameter gives a more granular context. This is documented on the jQuery API at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/:

> `jQuery( selector, [context] )`
> **`selector`** A string containing a selector expression
> **`context`** A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
>
> *By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. [...] Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').*

Answer (score 1):

It sure is!  Check it out here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 1):

This is usually called a scoped selector: http://coryschires.com/using-scoped-selectors-in-jquery/

I don't think it's very well called out on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.

Comment: That is the wrong link. It is actually not part of the selector documentation because it is a property of the `jQuery` function.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get prompted as I sometimes do that other answers had been posted before I submitted mine. If I'd seen someone noted it on the http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1 page I'd have just cancelled the answer.